# Set data for dynamic view

Tags: android, dynamic, reflection, data-binding, view

I am generating an dynamic layout from **API** **JSON** response. Once the layout is created I need to fetch values from a model class and assign it to the dynamically generated view. The problem is how can I achieve this in runtime? I know this is possible with **reflection** but is there any other alternative approaches. Since reflection is very slow this might affect app performance.

Comment: Assign id to your generated views and then you can simply find the view by id and assign data to it

Comment: The problem is not in finding the id. The problem lies in finding the right model class.